# How to test significance of difference between regression coefficients for multiple interaction categories?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have N multiple categories (a discrete interaction variable) and 
representative samples of which. I'm fitting a multi-variate X linear regression model to response variable Y for each category, is it possible to measure the statistical significance of the difference between the inferred coefficients of each categorical regression?

e.g. Category 1: X = [[1,4,3], [3,6,7], [2,1,5]...], Y = [0, 0.5, 1...] 
     and resultant $\mathbf{w}$ for $y = \mathbf{w}^T X$

Category 2: X = [[1,4,3], [3,6,7], [2,1,5]...], Y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7...]
     and resultant $\mathbf{w}$ for $y = \mathbf{w}^T X$
   ...Category N

I.e $H_0$: the difference between the coefficients is 0 (given perhaps the variance of the coefficients)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your terminology is a little bit confusing. Can you post some actual results / data, so that we may better assess the situation?

Comment: Have fleshed it out and made it more thorough. Thanks